# I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, parsing, parse-platform

Ok so I'm trying to work with Parse but whenever I run the app to check if everything went successful It says **I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful** In the logs
I Am following an android studio course I did everything like they did but it is still giving me this error.
Thanks.

This is my code

**Main Activity**

```
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Switch;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseAnonymousUtils;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseObject score = new ParseObject("Score");
    score.put("username", "nick");
    score.put("score", 45 );
    score.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          // OK
          Log.i("Success", "We saved the score!");
        }else{
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
  }

}
```

**Starter Application**

```
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // QhVarcmM9vPi paroli

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("myappID")
            .clientKey("QhVarcmM9vPi")
            .server("https://ec2-18-218-63-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse/")
            .build()
    );




    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

  }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
  ~ Copyright (c) 2015-present, Parse, LLC.
  ~ All rights reserved.
  ~
  ~ This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
  ~ LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
  ~ of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'

        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

Comment: Could you please try without ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent()); ?

Comment: I Tried it. it's still same.

Comment: I Tried "http://ec2-18-218-63-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse/ instead of "https://ec2-18-218-63-22.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/parse/
This time it said both unsuccessful and successful

Comment: I don't see in the code you share the usage of Firebase. It does not look Parse firing the error, but actually Firebase. Are you using it in any other part of your code?

Comment: No im not using firebase anywhere but I think its working now since its adding the stuff to my parse database